# Start a Service from an Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

In my app, I have an Activity from which I want to start a Service. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The application can start the service with the help of the [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html).startService method. The method will call the onCreate method of the service if service is not already created; else onStart method will be called. Here is the code:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
serviceIntent.setAction("com.testApp.service.MY_SERVICE");
startService(serviceIntent);
```

Answer (score 61):

Add this in your code

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ServiceName.class);
    startService(serviceIntent);
```

Dont forget to add service tag in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<service android:name="com.example.ServiceName"></service>
```

From the [Android official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html):

> **Caution**: A service runs in the same process as the application in
>   which it is declared and in the main thread of that application, by
>   default. So, if your service performs intensive or blocking operations
>   while the user interacts with an activity from the same application,
>   the service will slow down activity performance. To avoid impacting
>   application performance, you should start a new thread inside the
>   service.

Answer (score 2):

First create service from android `Manifest.xml` file (i.e from application tab) and give some name to it.
    On the activity on some event like click or touch to include the code from the service:

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Servicename.class));
}
```

If you want to stop the running or started service then include this code:

```
public void onclick(View v)
{
    stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext,Servicename.class));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [API Demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/index.html) have some examples that launch services.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Context.startService() method.

And read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Lifecycle).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start a service and it should run in background use START_STICKY in your corresponding service.

You can start service with on boot also,

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

And create receiver,

```
<receiver android:name=".auth.NotificationBroadcast" android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In Brodcast Receiver add,

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        System.out.println("BroadcastReceiverBroadcast--------------------ReceiverBroadcastReceiverBroadcastReceiver----------------BroadcastReceiver");

        if (intent != null) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

        switch (action) {
            case Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED:
                System.out.println("Called on REBOOT");
                // start a new service 
               startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Servicename.class));

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And your service is like,

Answer (score 0):

in `kotlin` you can start service from activity as follow :

```
   startService!!.setOnClickListener { startService() }
 
   private fun startService(){
    startService(Intent(this, HitroService::class.java))
   }
```