# How to start a service from an activity in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

am too much confused in starting a background service from an activity and am providing the code which i used to start the service from an activity.

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    Log.v("Running activities", manager.toString());
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
 if ("com.*.*.service.Service".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
     return true;
       }
    }
     Log.v("Currently running services in andorid phone", "other services");
    return false;
}
```

Above code is to check whether the service is running or not.If it is not means am doing this

```
if(isMyServiceRunning()) {
                          System.out.println("Service is running");
                        } else {
                          System.out.println("Service is not running");
                          Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
                          serviceIntent.setAction("com.*.*.service.Service");
                          startService(serviceIntent);
                        }
```

Suggest your answers and solutions to solve this problem.

Comment: What is the problem in your code ? Are you getting any exception or error ?

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334955/start-a-service-from-activity

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(yourActivity.this,yourservice.class);
  yourActivity.this.startService(intent);

Comment: If you can start your service then use 

Intent intent = new Intent(this, YOUR_SERIVICE_NAME.class);
startService(intent);

and also define 

<service android:name="your_package_name.YOUR_SERIVEC_NAME"></service>

in manifest.

Comment: No exception occurring always the code moves to the `else` part.

Comment: Then how can I identify whether the service is started or not @PRAKASHUBHADIYA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can start your service then use

```
public class YourService extends Service {

public static boolean isRunning = false;

     @Override
     public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
         return null;
     }

     @Override
     public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
         isRunning = true;
         return START_STICKY;
     }
}

if(!YourService.isRunning){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourService.class);
    startService(intent);

    Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date dt = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String strTime = sdf.format(dt);
    String strDate = dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

and also define

```
<service android:name="com.mypackagename.YourService"></service>
```

in manifest.

If you want check service running or not then use one static variable in service and check before start your service. If that false then start service.

Comment: I have added the `<service android:name="com.*.*.service"></service>` in manifest file.

Comment: This is possible or not?           `Intent service = new Intent();
        service.setAction("com.*.*.Service");
        startService(service);`

Comment: @SabariKarthik you give full package name in manifest file ?? if not then give full package name.

Comment: mostly for all declarations in manifest file I used to give the full package name which starts with `com.*.*.filename`

Comment: @SabariKarthik i edit my ans it work. if you check service is running or not then log in onStartCommand.

Comment: the code updated is working fine.But i want to get the service started time and date.how can I get the service started time and date?

Comment: @SabariKarthik i added time and date in my code please check.

Comment: And also suggest how to start a receiver after starting a service or before starting service.

Comment: @SabariKarthik go to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html and implement receiver in your activity.

Comment: I saw that link,that is full of theories @DivyangMetalia I need some examples because am new in Android development.

Comment: @SabariKarthik paste new question so i can add code in that.

Comment: see to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25725543/how-to-begin-a-receiver-function-programmatically-in-android