# How to begin a receiver function programmatically in android?

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I want to begin the receiver class by programmatically,I got some idea about how to start service programmatically and what is the difference between beginning service programmatically and receiver programmatically.Share your solutions and ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add receiver in service and get data from your activity. I add Activity and Service class below.

This is your main activity when you get receive data from service.

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
private MyReceiver receiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LocalBroadcastManager manager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
    receiver = new MyReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(YourServices.ACTION);
    manager.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

    if (!YourServices.isRunning) {
        startService(new Intent(this, YourServices.class));
    }
}

class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction() != null) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(YourServices.ACTION)) {
    AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MyServiceReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Start 20 seconds after boot completed
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 20);
    Log.v("background service", "STARTED////\\");

    //
    // Fetch every 1 hour
    // InexactRepeating allows Android to optimize the energy consumption
    service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            cal.getTimeInMillis(), REPEAT_TIME, pending);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here your service that send data when starting.

```
public class YourServices extends Service {

public static String ACTION = "your_action";
public static boolean isRunning = true;

private void broadcastData() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
            .sendBroadcast(intent);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    broadcastData();
    return START_STICKY;
}
}
```

Comment: One doubt what is use of this `public static String ACTION = "your_action";` @DivyangMetalia..And please if you wish to share your mail id means share to me.

Comment: @SabariKarthik if this ans useful you then give vote for ans.

That one action, Means you can clarify which receiver data broadcast. You can set any String in that. See my Profile in this sk ype id.

But when you define, register , send all are same.

If you want new broadcast receiver in that you can give diff name.

Comment: Shall i put the code in broadcast data or in onstartcommand itself @DivyangMetalia

Comment: what happens if the service starts programmatically rather than starting at bootup and also i have done code for service starting after boot completion.whether this will affect the while running the service in boot up. @DivyaMetalia

Comment: @SabariKarthik service start when bootup and its broadcast receiver also. Its not affect.

Comment: it is working @DivyangMetalia but my service is delaying in performance.

Comment: No seconds.it is delaying for 15 minutes.usually the service created by me wants to run every 1 hour.It is running for 15 min delay from usual time.

Comment: @SabariKarthik not understand. can you add some code when you start service.??

Comment: @SabariKarthik but where you start service. after any delay?
Also add log in your service.

Comment: Hi divyang once again am facing probms in location tracking @DivyangMetalia