# Android. Starting an Activity from a service

Tags: android, android-intent, service

How do I start an activity extending AppCompatActivity with an intent from a class extending Service

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Start a Service from activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334955/start-a-service-from-activity)

Answer (score 0):

Just call this code with your Activity:

```
startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK))
```